# Does "wiederhören" really exist?

Tags: verb

I know that *wiedersehen* exists together with its declination, but what about *wiederhören*? Does that verb really exist?

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher? Was sagt die Googlesuche? Was Google-ngram?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely used when making reference to a telephone call or similar:

> Wann hören wir uns wieder? Auf Wiederhören, bis zum nächsten Mal.

Comment: Indeed, this is used for all kinds of audio-only communication (radio, phone, etc.). The Duden however only lists the substantive [das Wiederhören](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/wiederh%C3%B6ren). The same is true for my copy of the Österreichisches Wörterbuch (39. Auflage)

Comment: For **wiedersehen**, both list a verb as well as the substantive

Comment: In addition to the canonical use as "goodbye" in a phone call, it also exists in a semi-offensive context (at least in the south), meaning as much as _"end of discussion, shove off"_.

Comment: Are you sure about _Wiederhören_ in this case? I'd happily use _Auf Wiederschau'n_, though.

Comment: Here in bavaria it is still used quite frequently, though it's mostly used by older people (60 years or older) to end phone calls; the younger generation doesn't use it at all or very, very rare. This seems to apply to all two-word hello- & goodbye-aliases though.

Answer (score 5):

As *wieder-* is a [common verb prefix](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/Praefixe/wieder.html?lang=en) many verbs can be found using this prefix. It is grammatically correct, and people will understand a composition *wiederhören* in analogy to *wiedersehen*. This is even more so as the composite nouns *Wiederhören*, and *Wiedersehen* are very common.

However there is a semantically notable difference in using *wieder* as a composite *vs.* using it as an adverb.

> - "Wieder"-Zusammensetzungen, in denen die Verbpartikel die Bedeutung 'zurück' hat, werden zusammengeschrieben, Beispiel: das Buch wiederbekommen = zurückbekommen.
> - "Wieder"-Zusammensetzungen, in denen die Verbpartikel die Bedeutung 'erneut, nochmals, ein weiteres Mal' hat, werden getrennt geschrieben, Beispiel: ein Kompliment wieder bekommen = erneut, nochmals bekommen.
>     <sup>[DWDS Orthografieregeln §34](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815202717/http://www.dwds.de:80/orthografieregeln/#pgf34_(E1.4))</sup>

This distinction is not always clear. Taken the rules above it would mean that you should use *wieder* as an adverb rather than a prefix when it has the meaning of *again*.

> Wir möchten das Lied wieder hören.
>   Ich möchte deine Stimme wieder hören.

But whenever the emphasis is put on the adverbial prefix rather than on the verb or if it resulted in an idiomatic expression it is  possible to build a separable composite (like it is done with *wiedersehen*).

> Können wir uns später wiederhören?

This composite form however is uncommon and should only be used in the context of telephone communication. Still the following adverbial construct would be grammatically correct as well:

> Können wir uns später wieder hören?

In summary we can build a composite *wiederhören* but if in doubt using a separated adverbial construct *wieder hören* may be a better alternative (and is probably [used more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wiederh%C3%B6ren,wieder%20h%C3%B6ren&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwiederh%C3%B6ren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwieder%20h%C3%B6ren%3B%2Cc0t1;,wiederh%C3%B6ren;,c0;.t1;,wieder%20h%C3%B6ren;,c0t1;,wiederh%C3%B6ren;,c0;.t1;,wieder%20h%C3%B6ren;,c0)).

Answer (score 4):

Auf wiedersehen is a "goodbye" for a face to face meeting that means "See you again." Auf  wiederhören is a "goodbye" for a "virtual" meeting (e.g a telephone conversation) that means "hear you again."

Answer (score 0):

it's typical in southern Germany and Austria to say Auf Wiederhören rather than Auf Wiedersehen (often they say auf Wiederschauen actually) at the end of a phone call. I've never heard a Bavarian say Auf Wiedersehen on the phone, that's a northern German thing.

Face to face Bavarians will say Auf Wiederschauen, Pfüat di or Servus rather than Auf Wiedersehen.

I've lived in Bavaria for 12 years and I've never heard Auf Wiederhören used as a kind of insult or semi-offensively. Maybe it's popular among the young..? Certainly all ages will say Basta to signal the end of a discussion: Das darst du nicht machen. Basta.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Auf Wiederhören exists, and, as Alison Demmer said, it is used in southern germany, like bavaria, and in austria, if you end a phone call. Auf Wiederschaun is used, for example, if you are in a shop and you exit it, you will say Auf Wiederschaun. You can compare it to "see you" in english. I am german and I never heard that it is used as an insult. So basically just listen to Alison Demmer and ignore my answer ;)

Comment: Some tips: 1) You can express your appreciation of someone else's answer by voting it up. 2) Maybe you want to cover "Auf Wiedersehen", too. 3) I am Bavarian, thus German, and study English in Austria.